# React | Dynamically build a form with react-hook-forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I am trying to dynamically render a form based on a series of questions which are provided from an API. The form should render the questions individually (one by one) and should not add the next question if it has already been triggered.

I have managed to do the above, quite easily but then when it comes to the logic surrounding a "multiple choice" I am starting to have great difficulty, whereby I am currently unable to determine the logic which could help the above scenario.

The API returns a resource such as the following to render a form:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'What is your name?',
    type: 'free-text'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'What is your age?',
    type: 'number'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'What is your occupations?',
    type: 'choice',
    allowMultiple: true,
    choices: [
      { value: 'Developer', goTo: 1 },
      { value: 'Engineer' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Any comments?',
    type: 'free-text'
  }
]
```

From the above example, `goTo` simulates what question that answer should go to. In this above example, after the use select "Developer" they will be greeted with "What is your name?" question again.

I have currently tried the following (React):

When the form is rendered it renders in the following format `{questionId}-{index}`. This is due to the same question being able to render on the screen at a given time, therefore "questionId" wouldn't be sufficient and would cause duplications.

Please find the link to codesandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-flower-pwyfbd

You will see that it works correctly for inputs, but then when using the choice the logic is messed up.

What should happen is the following:

- When "What is your name?" has a value -> load "What is your age?"
- When "What is your age" has a value -> load "What is your
  occupations?"
- When "Developer" option is checked -> load "What is your name" (due to the branching).
- Loop to the start.
- When "Engineer" option is checked -> load "Any comments?"

If "Developer" is unchecked, it removed all inputs / checkboxes that were generated from that checkbox.

If "Engineer" option is unchecked, it removes all inputs / checkboxes that were generated from that checkbox.

** please note, I could be going in the completely wrong direction with this and I am happy for suggestions on how to improve the code / a alternative method to go down **

Comment: Some progress has now been made and questions are assorted into "groups". It only renders the question once, but when unchecking it doesn't remove the question as the logic is yet to be implemented.